# modal effects to modalpopup

Tags: css, asp.net, modalpopup

I am attempting to apply different modal effects to a modalpopup as mentioned in the following site: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/

My code is:

```
 <div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
                    <div class="md-content">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlComment" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="450px" Style="display: none;">
                            <table border="1" class="commentTable" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px; width: 100%; height: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server" Text="Comments" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExistingComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" Width="100%" Rows="7" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblNewComment" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="False" Width="100%" Rows="7" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Button ID="bttnSave" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Save" OnClick="bttnSave_Click" />&nbsp&nbsp;
                                <asp:Button ID="bttnCancel" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Cancel" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modal" runat="server" TargetControlID="bttnHidden" PopupControlID="pnlComment" CancelControlID="bttnCancel"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is their example:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Read:</strong> Modal windows will probably tell you something important so don't forget to read what it says.</li>
                <li><strong>Look:</strong> modal windows enjoy a certain kind of attention; just look at it and appreciate its presence.</li>
                <li><strong>Close:</strong> click on the button below to close the modal.</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
/* Effect 1: Fade in and scale up */
.md-effect-1 .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

However, I am not sure this is the correct application or how to use this line: `<div class="md-overlay"></div>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

md-overlay is just the box that goes fullscreen and covers up the page, essentially graying out the content.  md-modal is the actual modal and sits on top of md-overlay.  If you have an example I can help, I've used these modals a few times.

Comment: I don't have an example except what is mentioned in the link which I will add.

Comment: what is your question or problem?  Yes that is how you would create the modal.  if you have the right CSS in place it should work.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear in my original post but the "effects" are not being applied. The modalpopup just appears transparent.

Comment: that going to be hard to debug without an example or jsfiddle showing the issue.  Can you show me your CSS at least?

Comment: I have added the CSS.

Comment: "The modalpopup just appears transparent." Are you seeing the content modal or just the overlay?  What happens when you manually add the class md-show to the md-modal?

Comment: Thanks for the response Riddle. The content modal does appear with the labels and text boxes but the panel itself is transparent. I removed the CSS class (CssClass="modalBox") that was initially on it and was working, and then wrapped the modal in the  <div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1"> as mentioned above. When I manually add the md-show as a class to the modal panel, I have the same transparent panel.

Comment: It sounds like its working.  Maybe you have other CSS effecting it?  Trying inspecting it and seeing where the transparency is coming from.